# Change views on UIScrollView so music changes

Tags: ios, xcode, uiscrollview, swift3, avaudioplayer

I have a UIScrollView setup but when I change view the music doesn't stop. How do I make it so the music stops when you change view?

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear( animated)
    meditationState = .on
    setTrackForPlayerWith(trackName: "Bigsur")
    player.play()
    player.numberOfLoops = -1

}
```

Here is the whole class from viewcontroller.swift. I've added the func scrollViewDidScroll and the self part that you mentioned but it's still not working.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let vc0 = ViewController0(nibName: "ViewController0", bundle: nil)

    var frame0 = vc0.view.frame
    frame0.origin.x = self.view.frame.size.width
    vc0.view.frame = frame0

    self.addChildViewController(vc0)
    self.scrollView.addSubview(vc0.view)
    vc0.didMove(toParentViewController: self)

    let vc1 = ViewController1(nibName: "ViewController1", bundle: nil)

    var frame1 = vc1.view.frame
    frame1.origin.x = self.view.frame.size.width
    vc1.view.frame = frame1

    self.addChildViewController(vc1)
    self.scrollView.addSubview(vc1.view)
    vc1.didMove(toParentViewController: self)

    let vc2 = ViewController2(nibName: "ViewController2", bundle: nil)

    var frame2 = vc2.view.frame
    frame2.origin.x = self.view.frame.size.width * 2
    vc2.view.frame = frame2

    self.addChildViewController(vc2)
    self.scrollView.addSubview(vc2.view)
    vc2.didMove(toParentViewController: self)

    let vc3 = ViewController3(nibName: "ViewController3", bundle: nil)

    var frame3 = vc3.view.frame
    frame3.origin.x = self.view.frame.size.width * 3
    vc1.view.frame = frame3

    self.addChildViewController(vc3)
    self.scrollView.addSubview(vc3.view)
    vc3.didMove(toParentViewController: self)

    self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width:     Double(self.view.frame.size.width * 4), height: Double(self.view.frame.size.height - 66))

    self.scrollView.delegate = self

  }

func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if scrollView.contentOffset.x > self.view.frame.size.x {
        player.stop()
    }
}
```

}

```
override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

}

ViewController3 where 'player' is declared:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

enum MeditationState {
    case on
    case off
}

class ViewController3: UIViewController {

    var player:AVAudioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()
    var player1:AVAudioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()
    var meditationState: MeditationState?
    var replicatorLayer = CAReplicatorLayer()
    var dot = CALayer()

    func updateTimer(){

        seconds += 1
        timerclock.text = "\(seconds)"
    }

    // Animation starts running

    func animation2() {

        // A layer that creates a specified number of copies of its sublayers (the source layer), each copy potentially having geometric, temporal, and color transformations applied to it.
        replicatorLayer = CAReplicatorLayer()

        // The layer’s bounds rectangle. Animatable.
        replicatorLayer.bounds = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 300.0, height: 300.0)

        // The radius to use when drawing rounded corners for the layer’s background. Animatable.
        replicatorLayer.cornerRadius = 10.0

        // The background color of the receiver. Animatable.
        replicatorLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.0, alpha: 0.0).cgColor

        // The layer’s position in its superlayer’s coordinate space. Animatable.
        replicatorLayer.position = view.center

        // calling this method creates an array for that property and adds the specified layer to it.
        view.layer.addSublayer(replicatorLayer)


        // connectng the animation to the content

        // An object that manages image-based content and allows you to perform animations on that content
         dot = CALayer()

        // The layer’s bounds rectangle. Animatable.
        dot.bounds = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 12.0, height: 12.0)

        //The layer’s position in its superlayer’s coordinate space. Animatable.
        dot.position = CGPoint(x: 150.0, y: 40.0)

        //The background color of the receiver. Animatable.
        dot.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.2, alpha: 1.0).cgColor

        // The color of the layer’s border. Animatable.
        dot.borderColor = UIColor(white: 1.0, alpha: 1.0).cgColor

        // The width of the layer’s border. Animatable.
        dot.borderWidth = 1.0

        //The radius to use when drawing rounded corners for the layer’s background. Animatable.
        dot.cornerRadius = 5.0


        //Appends the layer to the layer’s list of sublayers.
        replicatorLayer.addSublayer(dot)

        // number of copies of layer is instanceCount

        let nrDots: Int = 1000

        //The number of copies to create, including the source layers.
        replicatorLayer.instanceCount = nrDots

        // The basic type for floating-point scalar values in Core Graphics and related frameworks.
        let angle = CGFloat(2*M_PI) / CGFloat(nrDots)

        // The transform matrix applied to the previous instance to produce the current instance. Animatable.
        replicatorLayer.instanceTransform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(angle, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)

        // Type used to represent elapsed time in seconds.
        let duration: CFTimeInterval = 10.0

        // animation capabilities for a layer property.

        // An object that provides basic, single-keyframe animation capabilities for a layer property.
        let shrink = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.scale")

        // Defines the value the receiver uses to start interpolation.
        shrink.fromValue = 1.0

        // Defines the value the receiver uses to end interpolation.
        shrink.toValue = 0.1

        // Specifies the basic duration of the animation, in seconds.
        shrink.duration = duration

        // Determines the number of times the animation will repeat.
        shrink.repeatCount = Float.infinity

        // Add the specified animation object to the layer’s render tree.
        dot.add(shrink, forKey: "shrink")

        // Specifies the delay, in seconds, between replicated copies. Animatable.
        replicatorLayer.instanceDelay = duration/Double(nrDots)

        // The transform applied to the layer’s contents. Animatable.
        dot.transform = CATransform3DMakeScale(0.01, 0.01, 0.01)
    }

    // connecting the breathe in label

    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

    // instant delay

    @IBOutlet weak var instantDelay: UIButton!
    @IBAction func delayBtn(_ sender: Any) {

        dot.removeAnimation(forKey: "shrink")
        timer1.invalidate()
        seconds = 0
        timer2.invalidate()
        timerclock.text = "\(seconds)"
        time = 0
        timerLabel.text = "Breathe in"
        timerisOn = false
        pauseBtn.isHidden = true
        playBtn.isHidden = false

        label.isHidden = true
        replicatorLayer.isHidden = true
        instantDelay.isHidden = true
        instantDelay1.isHidden = false
        slider.isHidden = false
    }

    // Delay 1

    @IBOutlet weak var instantDelay1: UIButton!
    @IBAction func delayBtn1(_ sender: Any) {


        instantDelay1.isHidden = true
        instantDelay.isHidden = false
        label.isHidden = false
        slider.isHidden = true
    }


    //Slider for changing animation speed

    @IBOutlet weak var slider: UISlider!
    @IBAction func slider(_ sender: Any) {

    }

    @IBAction func speed(_ sender: UISlider) {
        view.layer.speed = sender.value

    }



    //Sound On button

    @IBOutlet weak var soundOn: UIButton!
    @IBAction func SoundOn(_ sender: Any) {
        meditationState = .on
    setTrackForPlayerWith(trackName: "Mute")
        player.play()
        soundoff.isHidden = false
        soundOn.isHidden = true
    }

    //Sound Off button

    @IBOutlet weak var soundoff: UIButton!
    @IBAction func SoundOff(_ sender: Any) {
        meditationState = .off
        setTrackForPlayerWith(trackName: "Bigsur")
        player.play()
        soundoff.isHidden = true
        soundOn.isHidden = false
    }

    //Timerclock at top of screen label

    @IBOutlet weak var timerclock: UILabel!

    // creating vars to set things

    var animation = CFTimeInterval()
    var timer1 = Timer()
    var timer2 = Timer()
    var time = 0
    var seconds = 0
    var timerisOn = false

    // connecting breathe in label

    @IBOutlet var question: UILabel!

    var arrayOfStrings: [String] = [""]

    // connecting timerclick and starting it
    @IBOutlet var timerLabel: UILabel!

    // changes the amount of time on the label of different labels
    func increaseTimer() {

        time += 1

        switch time {
        case 0 ... 7:
            timerLabel.text = "Hold"
        case 8 ... 10:
            timerLabel.text = "Breathe Out"
        case 11 ... 12:
            timerLabel.text = "Breathe in"
        default:
            time = 0
        }

    }

    // connecting the play button and vars
    @IBOutlet weak var playBtn: UIButton!
    @IBAction func play(sender: AnyObject) {

        bell(trackName: "Bell")
        player1.play()

        timer1 = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(ViewController3.increaseTimer), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        pauseBtn.isHidden = false
        playBtn.isHidden = true
        if timerisOn == false {


        timer2 = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(updateTimer), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
            timerisOn = true
        }
        animation2()
    }


    // pausing the timer with the vars

    @IBOutlet weak var pauseBtn: UIButton!
    @IBAction func pause(sender: AnyObject) {
        dot.removeAnimation(forKey: "shrink")
        timer1.invalidate()
        seconds = 0
        timer2.invalidate()
        timerclock.text = "\(seconds)"
        time = 0
        timerLabel.text = "Breathe in"
        timerisOn = false
        pauseBtn.isHidden = true
        playBtn.isHidden = false

        }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear( animated)
        meditationState = .on
        setTrackForPlayerWith(trackName: "Bigsur")
        player.play()
        player.numberOfLoops = -1

    }

   override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    time += 1
        do {
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient)
            print("AVAudioSession Category Playback OK")
            do {
                try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
                print("AVAudioSession is Active")
            } catch let error as NSError {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }

    }

        func setTrackForPlayerWith(trackName: String) {
            do
            {
                let audioPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: trackName, ofType: "mp3")
                try player = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: audioPath!) as URL)
            }
            catch
            {
                //ERROR
            }
        }


    func bell(trackName: String) {
        do
        {
            let audioPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: trackName, ofType: "mp3")
            try player1 = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: audioPath!) as URL)
        }
        catch
        {
            //ERROR
        }
    }

        override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }



}
```

Comment: change view means changing viewController, or scrolling to a new view on your scrollView?

Comment: Scrolling to New view on the scrollview

Comment: do you know what is the width of a view?

Comment: Not sure exactly, why do u ask?

Comment: are the views always as wide as the screen? does it cover the whole screen? maybe a screenshot would help.

Comment: Yes it does cover the whole screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can observe the changes made in your `UIScrollView` subclass in various delegate methods.

First of all, lets make sure your scrollView's delegate is assigned to the viewController. To do so, one option is to add following to `viewDidLoad()`

```
// `scrollView` should be whatever is your scrollView called in your VC
self.scrollView.delegate = self
```

Once this is done, lets make your `UIViewController` subclass conform to `UIScrollViewDelegate`

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {

    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        if scrollView.contentOffset.x > self.view.frame.size.x {
            player.stop()
        }
    }
}
```

`UIScrollViewDelegate` has numerous methods to observe changes in your scrollView. `scrollViewDidScroll(_:)` will be called every time there is an interaction with the scrollView, so as soon as the `contentOffset` is greater than the width of the view, lets stop the music.

Comment: Should I be putting this in the main viewcontroller that's linked to the screens or the individual ones. I put  'self.scrollView.delegate = self' in the main viewcontroller and it says it can't assign value to type viewcontroller to type uiviewdelegate? Then if I try and put it in the individual view controller instead, it says: value of type 'viewcontroller3' has no member 'scrollview' What should I do now?

Comment: Where is your scrollView defined? It should go into that ViewController.

Comment: scrollView is called scrollView in the main viewcontroller:     @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!

Comment: than it should go there. when you enter the line you might get an error, but than just do the second part i wrote, and the error should be resolved.

Comment: Ok, I'll try that.

Comment: Should the extension part go outside the viewdidload but in the same viewcontroller?

Comment: it should go outside of your classes scope. Place it below the last `}` bracket in your class.

Comment: It says declaration is only valid at file scope and use of unresolved identifier 'player' When putting the extension part outside the viewdidload but in the same viewcontroller

Comment: i will update my answer, so you will not experience this problem. Just add `, UIScrollViewDelegate` next where you define your viewController, and just the function below `viewDidLoad` function.

Comment: I got the  'self.scrollView.delegate = self' sorted and that part works but the func scrollViewDidScroll part still isn't working. It says: Value of type CGSize has no member 'x' and use of unresolved identifier 'player'. I've added the UIScrollViewDelegate to the class viewcontroller and it's still not working. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: could you post the whole class? it is hard to picture what is going on. add it to your question please.

Comment: Will do, I'll add it to the question this evening.

Comment: I've updated the question with it on. Please have a look and let me know. Thanks.

Comment: ok, so your player instance is not in this viewController. can you please post that viewController, where you have the player declared too?

Comment: and in `ViewController3` `viewWillDisappear` is not called? You should be stopping the player there.

Comment: That's right viewWillDisappear is not called, I've tried adding this in and it doesn't work. Any more ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for `viewWillDisappear(_:)`? In that method you can just add `player.stop()` to stop the music when you change views.

Comment: I've added:     override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        player.stop()
    }

Comment: But it's still not working. When you change the view you swipe right and when you do that the music is still on. Please let me know if you have any other ideas about how to solve it?

Comment: I realised viewWillDisappear is not being called for some reason

Comment: Ned - you forgot the delegate

Answer (score 1):

The smartass way to do this is just ....

let's say it's a vertical table.

**1.** Each table view cell has an audio track associated with it.  Think of one particular cell - C - it has an audio track A.

**2.** As the view scrolls (ie, whenever it is moving), just **get the frame** of C

**3.** Just take the height.  Then take the height of the screen SH.  Then get the distance of C from the center of the screen .. so Abs(SH - H).  Then just get that figure as a fraction (zero to one) of the SH.  So, Abs(SH - H)/H

(Depending on your situation, it may be better if that is divided by the height of cells, rather than screen height.)

**4.** Now ... simply set the **volume of all the audio track A, to that fraction**.  And in fact, simply do that for every cell.

As you scroll, the audio will mix between the various tracks.

"Magic"  :)